# What do the worker xenomorphs do when they are not gathering more hosts for eggs? What happens to the hive when the host supply is depleted?

Tags: aliens, alien-franchise, xenomorph

I have seen all of the Alien movies as well as the Prometheus series.  What do the drone or worker xenomorphs do once the host supply is depleted?  Does the queen keep on laying more eggs, or does she know when "enough is enough"?

Comment: Purely from deduction, we have a number of cases where there are more eggs than available hosts , so logically she keeps laying after the hosts are consumed, probably to entrap late arrival like happens in the first two movies.

Answer (score 1):

I think the implication is that if they run *completely* out of viable hosts in the reachable vicinity, they go into indefinite hibernation until they're woken up by the next bunch of hapless explorers.